# Getattr on package in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr

In Python, is there an equivalent of doing `getattr()` on a module for packages? In other words, is there a way to search for a function within a package like the one below?

```
Intents/
|-- __init__.py
|-- foo.py
|-- bar.py
|-- baz.py
```

Comment: To do so would require importing all modules in the package. Is that acceptable?

Comment: That is acceptable, they will all be quite small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to get any object from a python module:

```
In [4]: cat bla.py

def foo():
    pass

In [5]: import bla


In [6]: getattr( bla, 'foo')
Out[6]: <function bla.foo>
```

So you can walk all modules in a package, and `try... except` with `getattr` to find which module contains the desired class or function (you can also import any other top level object)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really say exactly what you wanted returned if the function is found, so the following just returns the module name.

If you added the following function definition to your `__init__.py` file:

```
def find_func(func_name):
    """ Return name of package module that contains named function. """
    import os
    import sys
    import traceback
    import types

    # dynamically imports all the python modules in sub directory
    package_path = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
    package_directory = os.path.split(package_path)[1]

    for fn in os.listdir(package_directory):
        globals_, locals_ = globals(), locals()
        # process all python files in directory that don't start with underscore
        if fn[0] != '_' and fn.split('.')[-1] in ('py', 'pyw'):
            modulename = fn.split('.')[0]  # filename without extension
            subpackage = ".".join([package_directory, modulename])
            try:
                module = __import__(subpackage, globals_, locals_, [modulename])
            except:
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
                raise  # reraise exception
            # see if this module has the named function
            obj = getattr(module, func_name, None)
            if isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType)):
                return modulename

    return None  # not found
```

You could then do the following in package clients:

```
import Intents

print(Intents.find_func('func_in_bar'))  # --> bar
```

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question?